# Not able to get array to return correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, arr

Create a function named findMax. It accepts one parameter, called numbers, that
represents an array of numbers. 
In your function, find the maximum number inside the array.
Return the result.

```
// Hint: You need to make sure that max always returns an 
// element of an array and not an arbitrary number.
```

[image: code]

The error message that I'm getting is

> You returned '4'. That isn't quite right. The max is 5.

Comment: Post the code in the question... not an image

Comment: return maxNumber?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in your screenshot seems to contradict the problem specs: the spec asks you to return an element, but your implementation returns an index. If you indeed want to find the max element, there's a fun one-liner for that:

```
function findMax(numbers){
    return numbers.reduce((max, n)=> n > max ? n : max);
}
```

If you're looking for the index of the max element, you can re-use the above function:

```
function findMaxIndex(numbers){
    return numbers.indexOf(findMax(numbers));
}
```

[demo](https://repl.it/JMEa)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing that is to keep changing the maxNumber every time the **for Loop** finds a bigger number, As follows:

```
num = [5, 3, 2, 7, 9, 10, 200];
findMax(num);

function findMax(numbers) {
    maxNumber = number[0];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > maxNumber) {
        maxNumber = numbers[i]
    }
  }
  return maxNumber;
}
```

This will return *200* and should work pretty good :)